# Google OR-Tools OP-TW implementation not respecting time window constraint

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Trying to implement an OP-TW problem using Google OR-Tools,however the results are not correct. Not sure where the issue is, hoping someone can guide me.

This is the Network of nodes/cost/time windows:
[Network of nodes/cost/time windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OJma.png)

This is the expected optimal solution:
[Expected optimal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LAnd.png)

However, based on the code below, I'm getting the below results.

***Total cost = 8.0
POI 1 to 5 is picked
POI 3 to 3 is picked***

Very new to Constraint Programming and Goolge OR-Tools.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below are the code I've created:

````
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import sys

model = cp_model.CpModel()

poi_count = 5

time_budget= 15

poi_list = range(0, poi_count)
all_but_first_poi = range (1, poi_count)

travel_cost = [[0,3,6,6,3],
               [3,0,4,5,3],
               [6,4,0,3,5],
               [6,5,3,0,4],
               [3,3,5,4,0]]

poi_hours = [[0,time_budget],
               [2,5],
               [3,6],
               [1,7],
               [5,8]]

profit=[0,5,8,1,4]

visits = {}
visit_start = {}

for i in poi_list:
  for j in poi_list:
    visits[i,j] = model.NewBoolVar('visit_i%i_to_j%i' % (i, j))

for i in poi_list:
  visit_start[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, time_budget, 'visit_start_i%i' % i)

#constraint 3.13
model.AddExactlyOne(visits[0,j] for j in range(1,poi_count))
model.AddExactlyOne(visits[i,poi_count-1] for i in range(0,poi_count-1))

#constraint 3.14
model.AddAtMostOne(visits[i,k] for i in range(poi_count-1) for k in range(1, poi_count-1))
model.AddAtMostOne(visits[k,j] for k in range(1, poi_count-1) for j in range(1, poi_count))

  #constraint 3.15/3.16
for i in poi_list:
  model.Add(poi_hours[i][0]<=visit_start[i]) #opening
  model.Add(visit_start[i]<=poi_hours[i][1]) #closing

model.Add(visit_start[0] == 0) #start with depot node opening

  #constraint 3.17
for i in range(poi_count):
  for j in range(poi_count):
    model.Add(visit_start[i] + travel_cost[i][j] - visit_start[j] <= time_budget * (1- visits[i,j])) #life time window of route constraint

model.Add(sum(travel_cost[i][j]*visits[i,j]   for i in range(poi_count-1) for j in range(1,poi_count)) <= time_budget)

# model.Maximize(sum(profit[i]  * visits[i,j] for i in poi_list for j in poi_list))
model.Maximize(sum(profit[i]  * visits[i,j] for i in range(1,poi_count-1) for j in range(1,poi_count)))

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    # print(visits)
    print(f'Total cost = {solver.ObjectiveValue()}\n')
    
    for i in poi_list:
      for j in poi_list:
        if solver.BooleanValue(visits[i, j]) == 1:
          print(f'POI {i+1} to {j+1} is picked')
          # print(visits)
else:
    print('No solution found.')```
````

Comment: Please define OP-TW. A simple search does not give any definition.

Comment: You do not have any constraint that defines a circuit. either use the routing library, or add a Circuit constraint. See https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/tsp_sat.py

Comment: @LaurentPeeron: OP-TW is Orienteering problem with Time Windows.
On the Circuit constraint, let me have a look. I thought those are only needed when we're consider this as a routing problem. The problem I have is not routing as we don't need all nodes to be visited.